# adding up a total using jade template engine

Tags: node.js, pug

I need to add up a total for a shopping basket but I dont know how to do this using jade

Here is how I thought I could implement it but it doesnt work, other ways I have tried just keep throwing errors.

Does anyone know how I would do this?

```
each item in bagItems
    - var total = total + item.realprice
p= total
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You wouldn't normally manipulate data in a template in *any* templating language. Work out the total in your app and pass the variable to your template.

Comment: @adam, I agree that generally you want to avoid data manipulation in your templates, but I think that display related logic belongs in templates and not in your controllers in the same way that business logic does not belong in your templates. I think this is a good example of a case where the data you need for display already exists (a sum is not data manipulation) and your controller need not structure data to accomodate how you want to display it now. The next step is controllers generating html class names for elements.

Comment: @adam, I agree that business logic and data manipulation do not belong in templates. I hope it was clear that what I was saying is that I think it is possible to take this ideal too far. The logical end to this line of thought is Mustache. I realize that there are many purists who think that Mustache (logic-less templates) is the embodiment of an ideal, but I believe that many people find that logic-less templates actually force them to put logic that belongs in templates elsewhere.

Comment: @Prestaul fair point, but dammit! The accept took me over 10k (hello moderator tools!) and the -2 took me back under :S

Comment: @adam: LOL! D'oh! But that raises an interesting question... So, at 10k they grant you rights... Do they take them away when you fall back under 10k?

Answer (score 6):

This should be pretty easy to do using the reduce method on your array.

```
p= bagItems.reduce(function(total, item) { return total + item.realprice; }, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Prestaul's `reduce` answer is a good solution, but I thought I'd answer also to give you a little more insight into what happened.

The issue is that variables created inside of an `each` loop are not available outside of the loop. Your code would look like this in JavaScript:

```
bagItems.forEach(function(item) {
    var total = total + item.realprice;
});
write("<p>" + total + "</p>");
```

I assume you're familiar with JS's variable scoping, but basically `var`s defined inside of a function are not accessible outside of it.

A second issue is that you're defining total as being equal to itself + something else, but you never give it an initial value, so it would end up as `undefined + item.realprice` which is `NaN`.

Here's an alternate solution that resolves both of those issues:

```
- var total = 0
each item in bagItems
    - total += item.realprice
p= total
```